# Config file format

Tags: parsing, configuration-files

does anyone knows a file format for configuration files easy to read by humans? I want to have something like tag = value where value may be:

- String
- Number(int or float)
- Boolean(true/false)
- Array(of String values, Number values, Boolean values)
- Another structure(it will be more clear what I mean in the fallowing example)

Now I use something like this:

- IntTag=1
- FloatTag=1.1
- StringTag="a string"
- BoolTag=true
- ArrayTag1=[1 2 3]
- ArrayTag2=[1.1 2.1 3.1]
- ArrayTag3=["str1" "str2" "str3"]
- StructTag=
- {
- NestedTag1=1
- NestedTag2="str1"
- }

and so on.

Parsing is easy but for large files I find it hard to read/edit in text editors. I don't like xml for the same reason, it's hard to read. INI does not support nesting and I want to be able to nest tags. I also don't want a complicated format because I will use limited kind of values as I mentioned above.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Bear in mind that all the advice you'll get will be subjective, as fans of format A will defend it to death over format B.

Comment: It often depends what environment you are using as that may have preconfigured classes, standards etc. eg a front end web project would make JSON the ideal candidate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about  [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) ? It's easy to parse, nicely structured has wide programming language support. If you don't need the full feature set, you could also use [JSON.](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: The format i currently use is very similar with JSON( I didn't know about JSON until now:P), but is hard to read for files with 300-400 lines or more.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357521/is-there-a-decent-json-editor-around

Answer (score 2):

Try [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaml) - is (subjectively) easy to read, allows nesting, and is relatively simple to parse.